# Held as opinion-based when I asked for resources

Tags: discussion, support, scope, on-hold, opinion-based

[Should I hyphenate GitHub topics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49177778/should-i-hyphenate-github-topics) asks whether there are *any recommendations, conventions or "best practices"* on usage of a certain tool. Note that I wasn't asking for the opinions of SO users, but rather asking whether there are any such standards out there, which has an objective answer (*Yes, there are these…* or *No, there are no such…*). Why is *that* opinion-based?

Compare to this theoretical question:

> My browser gives me a lot of freedom to write HTML however I want, e.g.
>
> ```
> <HtmL 
> ><buttON sTYLE=backgROUND:REd / \comment&go!
> #HELLo=wORld >->
> ```
>
> renders just fine: [image: button]
>
> Are there any recommendations, conventions or "best practices" for formatting HTML?

I assume such a question would be on-topic and get plenty of answers about HTML style guides and links to W3's and others' recommendations, and so on, so why was my question put on hold for being primarily opinion-based?

Comment: `I assume such a question would be on-topic and get plenty of answers about HTML style guides and links W3 recommendations` - nope, questions asking for resources are considered off-topic as well.

Comment: @Taryn Fair enough, but then it should be closed as off-topic, not opinion-based.

Comment: You've asked for recommendations, conventions or best practices - that seems pretty opinion based to me.

Comment: If there are standards, you can find them through research. Its as simple as that. If you don't find them then you can block yourself forever with the infamous "what if" questions like "what if it secretly does exist and the search engine is conspiring against me" but its just better to go to plan B. Usually, plan B makes for a better Stack Overflow question.

Comment: @Gimby My research path is Google search → SE search (although Google often finds things on SE) → Ask on SE. In this case, Google search was useless, as it only found me repos with topics related to whatever I'd search for, and SE (SO and SuperUser) didn't seem to have anything related. Hence my post.

Comment: Now also trust in Google's ability to tell you "Bro. Really. What you're looking for just isn't there to be found". And just to note: there is also Reddit, or Quora. That last step in your search path does not necessarily have to be SE, it should be "Ask somewhere appropriate".

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> Why is that opinion-based?

Why *isn't* it?  What determines whether a given answer is correct or incorrect?

> Note that I wasn't asking for the opinions of SO users

But you were.  You asked for any recommendations.  That's asking for SO users' opinions.

As for the second half of the question, asking for people to share opinions of other people expressed elsewhere is still asking for opinions, it's just second hand.

> but rather asking whether there are any such standards out there, which has an objective answer

Seems to me that you're not very familiar with how best practices work.  There are lots of different "best practices", and there is very often lots of disagreement (or at least not universal agreement) over what the "best practice" for a given task is.  There could be multiple competing "best practices", there could be on common one with a sizable minority of people that don't support it, etc.  But of course none of this makes the question not opinion based.  Again, asking for other people's opinions expressed elsewhere has all of the same problems as asking for the opinions of answerers (which, again you also did).

> I assume such a question would be on-topic

You assume incorrectly.  It has all of the same problems, for all of the same reasons.

> and get plenty of answers about HTML style guides and links to W3's and others' recommendations

We *don't want that*.  Hence why this close reason exists.

Comment: "There are lots of different "best practices", and there is very often lots of disagreement (or at least not universal agreement) over what the "best practice" for a given task is". By the exact same argument, all SO questions are opinion-based because you alway get lots of different ways to implement something, and there is often a lot of disagreement over what's the best implementation.

Comment: @Fatalize Yes, all questions have *some* amount of subjectivity.  No question is *entirely* objective.  It's a question of degree.  The close reason is for questions that are *primarily* opinion based.  Most questions are *primarily* objective, with some amount of subjectivity.  A good question is one that has an objectively correct answer, even if there is some opinions as to which of various possible correct answers is "the best".  This question is one that *has no objectively correct or incorrect answers*.  It's *only* asking for opinions.  That's the difference.